# Most recent values in time series

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple table with a time series in Excel. It collects values for samples over time.

[image]

How can I find the most recent value for each sample, and refer to them from another table or formula?

Comment: What do you mean by "refer to them"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula to return the rows for the max date of each Sample:

```
=FILTER(Table1,Table1[Date]=MAXIFS(Table1[Date],Table1[Sample],Table1[Sample]))
```

This formula is only entered in cell F2 in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Nice formula, I just wanted to note that this only appears to work if you have used "
INSERT TABLE" to create the table, it will not work on a named range and filtered data (which is how I first tried it:).